# Can I add a start menu option where documents, downloads, control panel resides?

Tags: windows-7

On windows 7, when you hover over the start icon, I see menus for Documents, Media, Pictures, Control Panel etc.

Can I add a document there that maps to a folder?

e.g.

Say I have a folder in the file system

c:\mystuff\blah

I want to link to mystuff, and then have it expand and show blah,... 
(I have already set my menus to auto expand)

Possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to add custom links to the right pane of the start menu you'll need a 3rd party application (e.g. [**WindowBlinds**](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/))

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5736-start-menu-enable-folder-library-pin-start-menu.html) article may be of assitance. It discusses the 3 methods available to Pin a Folder to the Start Menu.